# How is my error handler take precedence over earlier middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

using express.js for a project, first time using it for much more than messing around, and having some trouble with getting middleware to play nice.

My problem is that calls to my express static route, declared close to the top of the file

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

are actually being handled by the error handler, almost at the bottom of the file

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

...and I'm unsure why.  I know that JS isn't necessarily executing stuff in order, but it was my understanding that express will execute these in order, and `app.use` stuff at the bottom will occur after `app.use` stuff at the top - hence the need for `next();` - to pass to the next `app.use` handler?

Any ideas/wisdom?  Any help appreciated.

I have this code:

```
// Initial variable setup
var 
    express = require('express'),
    favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    swig = require('swig'),
    stylus = require('stylus'),
    nib = require('nib'),
    fs = require('fs'), 

    app = express()
;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

(settings.deploymentMode === 'dev') && app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

function compile(str, path) {
    console.log('STYLUS: Compiling CSS');
    return stylus(str)
        .set('filename', path)
        .set('compress', true)
        .use(nib())
        .import('nib');
}
app.use(stylus.middleware(
    {
        src: __dirname + '/public',
        compile: compile
    }
));

// Got some routing going on here... app.get statements, all working fine.

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});



// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('system/error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
} else {
    // Production error handler  - @TODO: Rewrite this one first.
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('system/error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });
}

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express error handling middleware is defined using four params, not three.

```
// From the specs
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
```

If you only defined it with 3 params, then it considers it a "normal" middleware and will call it unless a previous middleware, ends the request instead of calling `next()`. It appears that static middleware calls `next()`, probably to allow later middleware to log or compress its data.

Comment: Thanks, although the 404 handler is acting as normal middleware isn't it?  It seems to be there to catch any requests that are thus far unmet, and to generate a 404 to pass to the actual error handler at the bottom - using the 4 parameters.  Either way, taking it out has dealt with it - which is strange, because other than comments, it's what the express generator for Yeoman created!  Thanks for you help!

Comment: It appears that a successful "hit" on the static middleware doesn't actually stop the processing of the request, so it continues running them until it runs your 404 one.

Comment: Indeed, I would have thought that hits on my controllers would have stopped it though.  I'll keep digging, but for now it's more or less ok